# rxjs mergemap with response which returns an array

Tags: node.js, angular, rxjs

I have an ajax request which returns an Array of links. I need to use this array to send again ajax requests one per link in the array and then join the response of all inner ajax requests.

I have started like

```
ajax.post( url, data ).pipe(
 tap(response) // Array of links
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the RxJS `switchMap` operator to map from one observable to another and `forkJoin` function with JS `Array#map` to trigger all the requests in parallel.

```js
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

ajax.post(url, data).pipe(
  switchMap(links => 
    forkJoin(links.map(link => 
      ajax.get(link)
    ))
  )
).subscribe({
  next: (response: any) => {
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: (error: any) => {
    // handle error
  }
});
```